# How to create React component with components inside it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need something like this:

```
<Component>
    <Component.Child1>Test 1</Component.Child1>
    <Component.Child2>Test 2</Component.Child2>
</Component>
```

I noticed that some React UI frameworks have an implementation of this feature, e.g. [Ant Design](https://ant.design/components/layout/) (`<Layout />`), [Semantic UI](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/button) (`<Button />`), and [Blueprint](http://blueprintjs.com/docs/#core/components/tabs2) (`<Tabs2 />`).
I have tried to find how to do the same component but found an article about [dot notation](https://reactjs.org/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#using-dot-notation-for-jsx-type). With it, I can use child components, but can't use a parent as a component.
So, what is the appropriate way to create components that can be used in JSX with child components as well?

Clarification. What I have:

```
const Component = (props) => (<div className="someClass">{props.children}</div>)
const Child = () => (<div>Child content</div>)
```

What I want:

```
const App = () => (
    <Component>
        <Component.Child>Test 1</Component.Child>
    </Component>
)
```

Comment: What do you mean with *"but can't use a parent as a component"*?

Comment: Not able to understand what you mean by "can be used in JSX with child components as well". Can you elaborate?

Comment: What about
`const Component = () => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
const Child = () => (<div>{props.children}</div>)
const App = () => ( <Component> <Child>Test 1</Child> </Component> )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const Component = (props) => (<div className="someClass">{props.children}</div>)
const Child = () => (<div>Child content</div>)
```

Well you're so close! you just need to assign the child to the parent as a property.

```
Component.Child = Child;
```

Now you can use `<Component />` and `<Component.Child />` as you desire.